# My laravel application is not picking right route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

My laravel application should move to route "mango/public/4" but it moves to  "mango/public/4/4".
**Route file**

```
route::get('/{id}/edit','LaptopController@edit');
route::patch('/{id}','LaptopController@update');
```

**Update(view)**

```
<form method="post" action="{{$laptop->id}}">
    @csrf
    @method('PATCH')
   <table width="100%">
       <tr>
           <td>Enter Name</td>
           <td><input type="text"  name="name"></td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
           <td>Enter Description</td>
           <td><input type="text"  name="description"></td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
           <td><button>Update</button></td>

       </tr>


   </table>
</form>
```

**LaptopController**

```
public function edit($id){
        $laptop=Laptop::find($id);
        return view('update',['laptop'=>$laptop]);
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it moves to"?

Comment: i mean application is not picking right route that is specified in form action instead it is picking the wrong route that i mentioned above.

Comment: I see, have you tried to put a slash in front of the route because it becomes relative otherwise? Like so: `action="/{{$laptop->id}}"`

Comment: yes i tried but the the route becomes "localhost/4" but this route is not matching with that i specified in routes file so i will not go to update function in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easy if you name your route
When your action is just an id for example `action="4"`, it means that form will be sent to relative path, and that's why you have `/4/4` in your url

```
// web.php
...
route::patch('/{id}','LaptopController@update')->name('laptop.update');

// update view
<form method="post" action="{{ route('laptop.update', ['id' => $laptop->id]) }}">
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Problem solved by naming the route.

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect, it only outputs the ID:

`<form method="post" action="{{$laptop->id}}">`

You need to specify the route:

`<form method="post" action="{{ route('name-of-route', $laptop-id) }}">`

You can get the name of the route(s) by using `php artisan route:list`

Comment: yes exactly. i only need ID so that i can go to update function in controller but instead it is giving me ID as well as another route that is "localhost/mango/public/4/4". mango/public is the base route.

Comment: Sounds like a typo to me.

Comment: @AhsanAsif `action="4"` is a relative link. It'll just add on to the current URL. This answer is correct, and includes the fix. Try it out.